# IntelliJ Goland undo 'don't ask again action'（shortcuts conflict）?

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

I used the VScode keymapping plugin in Goland. eventlog show me a message means shortcuts conflict, then I click don't show me again ,how can I undo this notification .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close the IDE.
2. Find [the configuration directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) for your OS.
3. Open `options/other.xml` using any text editor.
4. Remove the line that contains `property name="muted.system.shortcut.conflicts.actions"`.